# How to input a Python + Flask variable into html tag attribute

Tags: python, flask

(Novice btw) I'm using Python + Flask

I have Python variable I want to place in as a substitute for a `value=" "`

My attempt: `value="{{ variable }}"` didn't work

```
<form>
  <textarea value="{{ result }}"></textarea>
</form>
```

```
render_template("home.html", result=result)
```

*Any guidance appreciated.*

Comment: Did you pass the variable in your render_template method?

Answer (score 0):

As per [chipchap31's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7222295/chipchap31) comment: remember to pass in the `variable` into your `render_template` method like so:

```py
variable = "foo"

render_template("page.html", variable=variable)
```

Once you've passed this in, you can access it in your Jinja template (HTML) like so:

```html
<tag value="{{ variable }}"/>
```

Comment: I did and I updated my post with that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Due to textarea not having a "value" attribute simply putting the Python variable between the tags will work.

```
<textarea>{{ result }}</textarea>
```